# bibliography option in French

Tags: bibliographies, french

I wonder if it is possible to get a complete French bibliography? For example, even if French accents can be used in bibtex, the categories still are in English. [image: In French, edition is "édition"]

In French, edition is "édition". I tried to change it directly in the bib file, but it didn't work.

Finally, does anyone knows a function in latex to automatically separate the articles from the books in the bibliography? Would it be more simple just to do two different bibliographies?

Thanks

Comment: Can you consider using `biblatex` and `biber`? Further `4e` should have a `superscript e`.

Comment: See https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/francais-bst

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `babel`, `babelbib`, and the `babplain` bibliographystyle, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[fixlanguage]{babelbib}
\selectbiblanguage{french}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\selectbiblanguage{french}
\bibliography{yourbibfile.bib} 
\nocite{ReeceCampbell}
\end{document}
```